# Shopping cart is empty when adding a product to the cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a bit of a strange one, when I add a product to the cart on my website I get "SHOPPING CART IS EMPTY". But when use a private window in Firefox or Chrome, it works fine. I am concerned it's not working for customers, I am unsure how to fix this.

Comment: I have faced the same issue on 1and1 hosting .. I was used limit of files .. I just deleted unwanted files all working perfectly

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153591)

Answer (score 6):

I have faced the similar issue once and fixed it by increasing the cookie life time to **86400** under

```
Sytem -> Configuration -> Web -> Session and Cookie Management
```

The Reason that I found out after doing some research on internet and different forum is that in Magento, by default cookie lifetime is set to 3600 (1 hour). But if the end users computer time runs ahead of server’s time, cookies will not get set for Magento frontend as well as backend. For example, end user’s computer time is 1 hour forward than server’s time, that means the cookie (holding user’s session id) will expire as soon as user logs in or tries to add an item.

Comment: @BenAnderson Try increasing it to 86400 or more.

Comment: If Cookie Lifetime "0" means what?

Answer (score 5):

It works fine on my side.
From this, and the fact that it works on private browsing mode, I can conclude that you have a cookie issue.
Try clearing your cookies and see if the error reproduces.
If that solves it, it will only solve it for your clients that might have the same issue.

Comment: Hi there its works when I clear my cache but if someone visits my website alot, wont they get cached and this will happen to them. My cookie limit is 8422 so surely thats enough.

Comment: I don't really know what happened for you but I would say you did something in the past that set a wrong cookie and that's when everything stopped working. You should click around and see if you can reproduce this now, after clearing the cookies. If you can not reproduce it you can leave it like that until a customer signals that he has the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When add products to cart, some times it returns to shopping cart empty page. I have hunted a lot via google. Most of the people met this same issue.

This is the problem of cookie issue. I have tried all of the cookie issue solution.

Increased cookie lifetime to 86400 in System->Configuration->WEB->Cookie Session
Set Cookie domain like .domain.com
Run Database repair tool
Cleared cache and Reindexed
Above solutions will be work for most of the people. But nothing to be working for me. But i’m sured it ‘s an issue related to cookie.

When i add product to cart, Again it redirect to empty cart page. I just enter checkout/onepage url directly on browser. Onepage is working fine for me. So products added to cart. But not showing in cart page.

So i have checked in chooseTemplate() method in Checkout/Block/Cart.php file.

$itemsCount = $this->getItemsCount() ? $this->getItemsCount() : $this->getQuote()->getItemsCount();

This $itemsCount value retuns empty some times. At that time, it choose Empty Template. So i have checked manually for get itemcount by following

$quoteItems = Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)
                          ->getQuote()
                          ->getItemsCollection();

And replace if ($itemsCount) { by if (count($quoteItems)>0) {

Now its working fine for me without any issue. It may help you to resolve shopping cart issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Hosting company where you host your website might have a limit on the number of files you can have in your account and you've reached it. Once you clear cache you delete files and it starts working again. Check your hosting file quota (limit).

Comment: Time to change your hosting company ASAP then! ^^