# cart is empty after add to cart (in private window working fine)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, ce-1.9.2.2

cart is empty after add to cart (in private window working fine) magento 1.9.2 programmatically.

i've used

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); //getModel
$cart->init(); 
$cart->addProduct($product, $qty);  // update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
$cart->save();
$quote->setIsActive(1);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Comment: did you checked in all browsers ? same issue everywhere  ? also try clearing your browser cookies and var/session once , than check in normal window.....

Comment: I agree with @BabyinMagento, sound like a cookie/session issue.

Comment: yes i've tried but not working cleared all session and cookie

Comment: @ssatish4u pls check [link1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57890/shopping-cart-shows-as-empty-upon-clicking-add-to-cart) , [link2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71166/shopping-cart-is-empty-when-adding-a-product-to-the-cart) , [link3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80854/add-to-cart-button-brings-you-to-an-empty-cart-for-certain-products-need-help-tr) and [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519660/magento-add-to-cart-shows-empty-cart)....